# Delete Permanently Data From Database

Tags: codeigniter

Hello i need help how to delete my database permanently, when im delete data from my app its not deleted from database, for controller use this to delete

```
/**
 * deleted data | SET is_deleted to true
 */
public function delete() {
    $response = [];
    $ids = explode(',', $this->input->post($this->pk));
    if (count($ids) > 0) {
        if($this->model->delete($ids, $this->table)) {
            $response = [
                'action' => 'delete',
                'type' => 'success',
                'message' => 'deleted',
                'id' => $ids
            ];
        } else {
            $response = [
                'action' => 'delete',
                'type' => 'error',
                'message' => 'not_deleted'
            ];
        }
    } else {
        $response = [
            'action' => 'delete',
            'type' => 'warning',
            'message' => 'not_selected'
        ];

    }

    $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
        ->set_output(json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT))
        ->_display();
    exit;
}
```

Comment: How does your model looks like? We have no info about your SQL queries.

Comment: Please show `$this->model->delete` code.

Comment: here :
 public function delete_permanently($id) {
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->where(self::$pk, $id)->delete(self::$table);
  $this->db->trans_complete();
  return $this->db->trans_status();
 }